# Java Rest does not Work When using two queryParameters

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have set up a method as follows:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/{activityLocator}/item/{itemUid}")
@Override
public Obj getItemWidgetParams(
        @PathParam("activityLocator")
        String activityLocator,
        @PathParam("itemUid")
        String itemUid,
        @QueryParam("options")
        ItemWidgetInitOptions options,
        @QueryParam("mode")
        String mode) throws Exception
{
    return something;
}
```

The problem is that when I use no query parameter or just one (any of the following two uri), this function is called:

1) hostname/service/stepActivity/activityLocatorID/item/1

2) hostname/service/stepActivity/activityLocatorID/item/1?mode=5

but as soon as I add the second query parameter, the function is not called anymore and I get an error message in response:

hostname/service/stepActivity/SerializedSession:activitylocatorID/item/1?mode=5&options=blah

Any idea what I do wrong?!

Comment: First guess without knowing the error is that the framework needs you to tell it how to convert a string into a ItemWidgetInitOptions

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `ItemWidgetInitOptions options` to `String options`.
You may want to give it a default value if its optional.

Answer (score 0):

As km1 said you may need to change your parameter options.

```
    @QueryParam("options")
    ItemWidgetInitOptions options
```

According to [jersey documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html) :

> In general the Java type of the method parameter may:
>
> 1. Be a primitive type;
> 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument;
> 3. Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single
>    String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String) and
>    java.util.UUID.fromString(String)); or
> 4. Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above.
>    The resulting collection is read-only.